# UV Layout for texturing - stretched areas

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have made myself a simple enough pillar. (gif below)

https://gyazo.com/f0a73328a9e2b69d51f092e56f9c9c5d

The issue I am having is with the UV. I have tried unwrapping faces separately, in various groups and, as you see it in the gif, one side of the pillar at a time.

The issue is that whilst the more compact faces look amazing with the texture, the larger areas look stretched out.

How do I make all areas of the UV map work, so that the texture doesn't stretch?

Idealy I'd like to be able to slap a tileable texture on the bake map in PS and it all look amazing in world (this is for sl)

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58971/how-to-get-rid-of-stretches/58972#58972. But with a difference as SL allows UV to be larger than the texture : so you can stretch the UV maybe here in one direction if you dedicate a part of the texture for that.

Comment: Hi lemon, so based on that link... I would need to separate the longer parts of my UV map, and stretch them until the texture fits properly?

Comment: Yes. Just select the corresponding face in the 3D view so that only this face appears in the UV map view. Then place/stretch the UV as needed.

Comment: Hi lemon, Thank you, that works exactly as I need it to.